Artifacts on semi transparent object in Material view
I have modeled a simple perfume bottle with some transparency on its body. It's looking fine, but the only issue are the weird 'blocky' artifacts that appear 'only' in Material view. They do not appear in Rendered view.
Screenshot and the blend file are attached below.
Could some one please help me finding the issue?
I'm not a pro and learning the intricacies of Blender every day. Thanks.
Blend file: https://easyupload.io/wyqrlq
The blocky artifacts:


The Material preview uses the Eevee render engine, in Eevee the glasses are not accurate, you can still deactivate the Show Backface option to avoid what you point out but it still won't be as accurate as in Cycles:


Thank you so much for the quick response. So Material preview is based on EEVEE. Great info, I didn't know. I was thinking some leftover baked textures are getting projected.
Thanks again and I will mark this as the chosen answer when the 5 minutes pass.
